# Finding the owner of an app with the API key

Tags: facebook-graph-api, api-key

Someone built an app for the organization I work for but no one can remember who it was and we need to make changes to the app. The only information we have is the API key. We've tried navigating to the apps page by adding the key at the of http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=XXXX but we're redirected back to our website. Is there a way we could figure out who administers the app? Maybe using Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive you can not use that. I would navigate to the app itself, and on the bottom of the page inside on the right side, for "ctrl+f" for find, and click "Report/Contact this App" and then send a message to the developer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option. I tried "ctrl+F" and looking all over the page. The only thing on the bottom right is the standard "About · Create an Ad · Create a Page · Developers · Careers · Privacy · Cookies · Terms · Help" content. But thanks for the feedback.